# Как установить выделение (подсветку) на img в contenteditable в FireFox?

Tags: javascript

прошу помощи: мне необходимо при клике на картинку подсвечивать ее (наложить на нее выделение). Интересует не присваивание класса с какой нибудь цветной рамкой или прозрачностью, а именно физическая установка selection. Код ниже работает только для IE или Chrome. Как унифицировать его в том числе и для FireFox?

```
var img = event.target;
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStartBefore(img);
range.setEndAfter(img);
s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(range);
```